# Is it wrong to comment old posts with "noise"?

Tags: discussion

I was looking for something on [C++ code file extension? .cc vs .cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546107/4440053), and saw someone asking what to do on Windows when it comes to case-sensitivity of filenames.

Two people had answered already, with some important points, but I figured another important point (biased or not) was missing from the comments. Note: comments are not answers, they are expansions on other answers, to fill the gaps, or ask for clarifications.

I quickly got a response from a highly-ranked user, in short telling me to "shut up":

[image: OP left a comment saying, "Don't use Windows to program in C or C++". Clifford responded with, "Don't post nonsense irrelevant comments on antique posts."]

I defended my point, but asked myself: is it worth adding more noise to the noise the high-profile user already was adding? **Was my comment really noise?**

Back and forth, I ended up feeling/getting attacked by the user for my age and lack of experience (and indirectly lack of karma).

[image: Clifford said OP's opinion is less informed based on age. OP responds with "I hope at your age you are happy."]

After this, the user decided to leave a last note claiming I was going against the guidelines for adding noise to the comments. I understand Stack Overflow as a Q&A place, where people can learn from other experienced users. My experience was simply: don't use something if you have an alternative that causes you less issues. So I added it.

The guidelines are not perfect, and that's why they are guidelines, not rules. I started nothing, I simply added a way to handle a problem.

Then, the user decided to delete their comments. I had taken screenshots of the conversation prior to the answers because I was getting heated up. I couldn't resist to answer back to their last post:

[image: OP says their initial comment wasn't more noisy than the ensuing argument.]

**TL;DR:**

Is it wrong to answer old posts? What to do when other users believe they can dictate how we should use this site? When is it okay to just "not answer back"? Should I delete my answers to their comments?

Comment: Frankly, that just amounts to a bad use of comments. Although it is true that the story on C and C++ development on Windows isn't as good as in other platforms, do you still think that your comment is constructive and relevant enough to be posted there?

Comment: i agree your comment is spam and does not fit the requirements for commenting https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: I do not see how my first comment I added is spam. I do consider the rest of the discussion to be spam, though. I know many developers keep using Windows to develop, and ask themselves how to deal with many problems that would easily go away if they developed on another platform. That's why I added it as a comment.

Comment: And why adding it as a comment to an existing answer if that comment, just as you suggested, makes an actual answer? _The comments are not the place for answers._ This was the first mistake. The second one was to follow up on the heated commenting. Next time, it's best to just clean up, flag and move on.

Comment: In truth, "*don't use Windows to program in C or C++*" doesn't sound like "a way to handle a problem", as you claim. Khandelwal may have asked a question indeed, but this was back in 2015, your comment doesn't address it, comments are not answers, and actually you are not even replying to them (you should have used their handle in order for them to be informed of your comment). It does seem noise to me.

Comment: The question itself had nothing to do with filenames on Windows. The question that answered mentioned there was a difference between `.c` and `.C`, and someone asked how to deal with this on Windows. My answer: don't deal with it on Windows.

Comment: I could have used their handle to get their attention, but I figured _that_ would be noise, as they have probably already learned this in 5 years. People reading the post (as me, or other new developers), would see it instead.

Comment: This was of course not what you answered. It's fine to request advice here for similar issues, but please be accurate, stick to the facts, and don't move the goalposts

Comment: I see now that my original comment might be a bit "extended", in the sense that I answered a more generic question than what I actually meant. The critique I got, though, was that I was answering an old point, and didn't have enough experience (or age) to answer.

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted for actually asking how to use this site appropriately on meta?

Comment: Because users will still vote here on Meta based on the question's research effort, agreement with the contents, and overall presentation.

Comment: The post is discussion-tagged, so agreement with the post or not shouldn't affect their rating. The only research which makes sense is to read the guidelines regarding comments, which I read. I didn't understand how my original comment was going against these, although I understand now that I might have expressed myself a bit poorly. I see nothing wrong with the presentation. **In conclusion**: delete the heated comments, explain what I meant instead, and move on.

Answer (score 16):

"Don't use Windows to program in C or C++" is a comment with the only *visible* purpose to start a flame war. The proper way (which unfortunately was not followed there) was to flag the comment as "no longer needed" or "unfriendly or unkind" and move on.

Please remember that SO is a place to ask *practical questions* about programming. This means that people have a lot of restrictions on the type of solutions they can use. All comments and answers to "I need to do X on Y framework/platform" that simply only state "use Z" are not appropriate as an answer to that particular question.

Also since questions looking for recommendations are off-topic on SO, a comment or an answer "use X (Windows, Linux, iPhone, NeXT,...)" is unlikely to be on-topic on any question/answer.